# DataGridView Filter through Textbox using bindingsouce

Tags: vb.net

I wanna make a Search on Data Grid View in C# and SQLite, but I don't have Binding Source for Datagridview. I fill Datagridview with following code:

```
Private Sub TxtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtSearch.TextChanged

Dim bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource
AccountTransactionLedgerDetailsDataGridView.DataSource = bs
bs.Filter = String.Format("AccountName LIKE '%{0}%'", TxtSearch.Text)
AccountTransactionLedgerDetailsDataGridView.Refresh()  

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: An image of an empty grid doesn't help anyone. If you've changed your code then we need to see the new code to be able to work out what's wrong with it.  If you haven't changed your code then obviously that is the issue.  I've explained what to do and I've provided code examples.  The next step is for you to actually do it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a new `BindingSource` every time you want to filter.  Add the BindingSource to the form in the designer and then use it when you first bind, e.g.

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

Then you only need one line to filter:

```
myBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("AccountName LIKE '%{0}%'", TxtSearch.Text)
```

EDIT:

I just tested this code (which you can do too) and it worked exactly as expected, i.e. exactly as you want:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table As New DataTable

    table.Columns.Add("Rank", GetType(String))

    With table.Rows
        .Add("First")
        .Add("Second")
        .Add("Third")
        .Add("Fourth")
        .Add("Fifth")
        .Add("Sixth")
        .Add("Seventh")
        .Add("Eighth")
        .Add("Ninth")
        .Add("Tenth")
    End With

    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    BindingSource1.Filter = $"Rank LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%'"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your rly. But agin same issue happens

Comment: What issue? You state in your post you want this in C# but you're posting in vb.net. Are you trying to put this code in a C# project? Also, if you are doing this in VB.Net, can you edit your post and add your new code based on what jmcilhinney suggested and explain what is happening?

Comment: @jayamanickam An assumed issue may be that you are still doing all of this in the textchanged event when you should only have the filter in your textchanged event. The other 3 lines should be somewhere like form_load so that you fill the dgv and then filter by what you enter into your TxtSearch textbox.

Comment: Im already binding datagridview. As per your instruction i do that, but again nothing will happens. kindly do need full

Comment: If you do as I showed here then it will work.  If it's not working, you're not doing what I showed here.  If you don't show us what you are doing, we can't tell you what's wrong with it.  Edit your question and show us the code you're using to retrieve the data and bind the grid, as well as your current code for filtering.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney. I edit my query above please find the screenshot on my question